# Android Upload Image to Server, write path with text fields to a database and retrieve to list view

Tags: java, android

[Images and Text Uploader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeHFG.png)

Hallo Coders, i am new in Android. i have the above app to upload images to a server and write the image path to a database alongside the user inputted data as seen in the app UI. So far its uploading only one image with the below code and writing the path as appropriate. I am unable to pass the textview data alongside the image path to a mysql DB. I need the following.
1 Upload multiple images to server and write the images path and the other values to a mysql database.
2. Display the images from the server using the state/county select on a listview (Vertically or Horizontally)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/PhotoUpload/upload.php";
public static final String UPLOAD_KEY = "image";



private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

private Button buttonChoose;
private Button buttonUpload;
private Button buttonView;

private ImageView imageView;

private Bitmap bitmap;

private Uri filePath;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
    buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
    buttonView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonViewImage);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        filePath = data.getData();
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return encodedImage;
}

private void uploadImage(){
    class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Void,String>{

        ProgressDialog loading;
        RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Uploading...", null,true,true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            loading.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
            Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
            String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);

            HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();

            data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);
            String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL,data);

            return result;
        }
    }

    UploadImage ui = new UploadImage();
    ui.execute(bitmap);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == buttonChoose) {
        showFileChooser();
    }

    if(v == buttonUpload){
        uploadImage();
    }

    if(v == buttonView){
        viewImage();
    }
}
```

Comment: `I am unable to pass the textview data alongside the image path to a mysql DB.` The textview data does not even reach your php script. And the image path will be a path on your server. Not a path on your Android device. So you mean: i am unable to pass the textview data to my php script?

Comment: Thanks blackapps. I just want all the above parameters as follows( images to uploads folder and the path and names to a mysql database.

Comment: Thanks sir @blackapps. That's exactly what I want. 1. Sending the data from the above Android app to your php script. 2. Receiving the data in your php script. 3. Handle the received data in your php script by putting th1. Sending data from Android to your php script. 2. Receiving the data in your php script. 3. Handle the received data in your php script uploading the images yo a folder and writing the image paths and the inputted parameters into a mysql database table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked as required by initialising all aspects in the code.